# MAVEN Version Ranges by Plugins

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

How can I tell maven 3 to use the version ranges conventions by plugins?

Maven/JDK Version:

`$ ~/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/java/maven/bin/mvn --version`

```
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 14:51:28+0100) 
Maven home: ~/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/java/maven 
Java version: 1.8.0_101, vendor: Oracle Corporation 
Java home: ~/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_101_x64/jre 
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8 
OS name: "linux", version: "4.4.0-78-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Snippet from `pom.xml`

```
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>[3.0.0,)</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
...
```

Execution `mvn clean install`

```
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:[3.0.0,) or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:jar:[3.0.0,): : Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:pom:[3.0.0,) from/to nexus (http://nexus/content/groups/public): Illegal character in path at index 77: http://nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-war-plugin/[3.0.0,)/maven-war-plugin-[3.0.0,).pom
```

Comment: First you should not use version ranges at all nor for plugins nor for dependencies. Just simply use fixed versions...which will solve the subject...

Comment: Furthermore defining the plugin version in the build section is not the best. Better use pluginManagement for this...

Comment: BTW: I would recommend to upgrade to Maven 3.3.9 or 3.5.0...

Comment: using version ranges is a valide pattern in maven. I cannot understand your first comment!

Comment: I didn't said it's not a valid pattern. I wrote that I recomment not to use them. In the area for plugins it is not simply valid. You should simply define the version of maven-war-plugin using `3.0.0` that's it...

Comment: You wrote I should not use version ranges at all nor for plugins nor for dependencies. Your recommendation refers to upgrading the Maven version. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Actually, there is a use-case for version ranges in dependencies, and I have it:  I am developing a maven plugin, and it is part of a much larger source tree.  I want to use the local version if it is available, and the last-published version otherwise - i.e. a fixed range of [A,B].  In general, I agree, range deps are a terrible idea, but in this one case it is tremendously useful (you can cheat using <dependencyManagement> and maven appears to resolve the version from there, but it does complain).